# How to keep the ones in the Diagonal of sns.heatmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, correlation

I want to plot the correlation Matrix with sns.heatmap and have some questions. This is my code:

`plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
mask =np.zeros_like(data.corr())
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
sns.heatmap(data.corr(), mask=mask, linewidth=1, annot=True, fmt=".2f",cmap='coolwarm',vmin=-1, vmax=1)
plt.show()`

and this is what i get:
 [Correlation Matrix][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX2oN.png \

Now i have some questions:

1) How can i keep the ones in the diagonale?

2) How can i change the position of the x-axis?

3) I want that the colorbar goes from 1 till -1, but the code is not working

I hope someone can help.

Thx

Comment: Just in case someone still wants to know: In order to show also entries on the diagonal, you just need to add `k=1` in `triu`, like: `mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool), k = 1)`. It will remove `True` from diagonal in the mask array and diagonal won't be masked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check `data.corr()`, because your code is correct and gives the diagnoal (see below). One question is: you use `np.triu` but the picture you show displays  `np.tirl`.

Here the code I've tested - the diagonal is there:

```
N = 5
A = np.arange(N*N).reshape(N,N)

B = np.tril(A)

mask =np.zeros_like(A)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

print('A'); print(A); print()
print('tril(A)'); print(B); print()
print('mask'); print(mask); print()
```

gives

```
A
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]

tril(A)
[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5  6  0  0  0]
 [10 11 12  0  0]
 [15 16 17 18  0]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]

mask
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

**edit: suplement**

you could re-fine the mask, e.g.

```
C = A *mask
D = np.where(C > 1, 1,C)
print('D'); print(D)
```

gives

```
D
[[0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

The first element of the diagonal of D is now a Zero since the first element of the diagonal of A is a Zero too.

**edit: suplement 2**

```
F = np.tril(A,-1)
E = np.eye(N)
G = E + F

print('F'); print(F); print()
print('E'); print(E); print()
print('G'); print(G); print()
```

gives

```
F
[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5  0  0  0  0]
 [10 11  0  0  0]
 [15 16 17  0  0]
 [20 21 22 23  0]]

E
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]

G
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [10. 11.  1.  0.  0.]
 [15. 16. 17.  1.  0.]
 [20. 21. 22. 23.  1.]]
```

Comment: yes but in tril(A) there are also the zeros. How can i keep the ones and but not the zeros?

Comment: Do I get it right: whenever there is a zero, you want that this zero is not displayed and not colored (even  within the tril) ?

Comment: Right. I dont want the zeros but only the ones in the Diagonale. In my Picture you can see, that i have everything that i need, only the ones in the Diagonale are not there. Have u an Idea? And thx a lot for helping!

Comment: Ok Thx i will try at home, sorry must work. Have u maybe an idea for the other problems?

Comment: To (3): try something like `vmin = -1.1, vmax = 1.1`. To (2): I do not understand the question.

Comment: Hallo pyano, with vmin and vmax 1.1 not working. The second question: I want to have the x-axis above the grafik, just change the place

Answer (score 1):

`mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)]` will define the triangle (including diagonal)

`mask[np.eye(mask.shape[0], dtype=bool)]` will define the diagonal.

If you put those together, you can control them independently. (Be aware you need to set the triangle **before** the diagonal).

```
def plot_correlation_matrix(df, remove_diagonal=True, remove_triangle=False, **kwargs):
    corr = df.corr()
    # Apply mask
    mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
    mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = remove_triangle
    mask[np.eye(mask.shape[0], dtype=bool)] = remove_diagonal
    # Plot
    # plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, **kwargs)
    plt.show()
```

So this command will generate the matrix, removing the upper triangle, but keeping the diagonal:

```
plot_correlation_matrix(df[colunas_notas], remove_diagonal=False, remove_triangle=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change of the position of the x-axis**

Since I'm not experienced with seaborn I would use matplotlib to plot the heat map ([here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947281/diagram-graphical-options-to-display-cartesian-product-in-juniper-notebook-pytho/54948353#54948353)) an then use matplotlib's `twinx()` or `twiny()` to place the axis where you want to have it ([here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772673/matplotlib-imshow-twiny-problems)).

(I think that can be done with seaborn too - I just do not know it)